# $cordovaFile.writeFile writes blank file

Tags: cordova, pdf, local-storage, device, writefile

I used writeFile(path, file, data, replace) method  in $cordovaFile to write new file(pdf, jpg, text ).
as a data I got data stream from restful service ..(it looks like  %PDF-1.5↵%����↵1 0 obj↵..) 
The problem is I can write a file but it opens as a blank pdf but file size is correct.
for data field I used data stream itself, blob object(var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });) ,

This is my code

```
var path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
$cordovaFile.writeFile(path, "myCreatedPdf.pdf", blob, true)
.then(function(success){
    console.log("file");
    $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
        success.target.localURL,'application/pdf'
    );
}, function (error) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

Please help me out.... any ideas...?

Comment: had you tried to create a text file first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this method text files can write correctly. problem was .pdf .png file writing. so I use this method to write file. that works for me.

```
function saveFile(pdfBlob, fileName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var filePath = "";
    try {
        console.log('SaveFile: requestFileSystem');
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('SaveFile_Err: ' + e.message);
        deferred.reject(e);
        throw ({ code: -1401, message: 'unable to save report file' });
    }


    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("TokenReader", { create: true }, gotDir);
    }

    function gotDir(dirEntry) {
        //console.error('SaveFile: gotFS --> getFile');
        //dirEntry.getFile("rptSampleNew.pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        //console.error('SaveFile: gotFileEntry --> (filePath) --> createWriter');
        filePath = fileEntry.toURL();
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        //console.error('SaveFile: gotFileWriter --> write --> onWriteEnd(resolve)');
        writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.resolve(filePath);
            }, 100);
        };

        writer.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log('writer error: ' + e.toString());
            deferred.reject(e);
        };

        writer.write(pdfBlob);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
        deferred.reject(error);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```